¿Como saber que tipo darle a una variable en TypeScript?
Tengo una duda de como puedo saber que tipo darle a una variable o parametro de una funcion, por ejemplo:
const funcion = (parametro: tipo)=>{
  console.log(parametro)
}

si en este caso el parametro fuera un request/response, o un evento de React, ¿como puedo saber que tipo le tengo que dar? (evitando usar any).
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Y al hacer ese console.log(parametro) no te dice que tipo es?

Puedes usar typeof, incluso algunas veces pasando el cursor sobre la variable el mismo VSCode te dice de que tipo es, si quieres hacer un tipo de dato en específico para una respuesta de tu API puedes usar Quicktype.io

"Cómo saber qué tipo"? Pues es que el tipo eres tú quien lo decide. Si es una callback que vas a pasarle a react por ejemplo y quieres saber exactamente qué recibe, pues para eso está la documentación!! Es tu código, tú eliges qué recibe cada función que escribes, como he dicho, si es para usarla con una librería o framework, la documentación es quien te dice qué vas a recibir en cada caso. Leer documentación es sano, es la manera de hacer las cosas.
